# Problem in updating contact email address

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to update contact email address using this code

```
String selectEmail = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='"  + 
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";
    String[] emailArgs = new String[]{Id}; 
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withSelection(selectEmail, emailArgs)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, email)
    .build());
```

I am getting "Id" using this code

```
String[] returnVals = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID};
   this.cur = this.cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
               returnVals, 
               ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " = \"" + phoneNumber + "\"", 
               null, 
               null);
```

My questions are

1. Am I using correct way for getting Contact_ID using the Phone number
2. Contacts are not updating correctly, it is changing all fields like email, name and number. Am I doing something wrong?

Need help.

Answer (score 1):

Please format your code, before reading this answer... ;)

You can find an example how to update contacts [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.html) and an example to do a number lookup [here](http://github.com/TomTasche/SayMyName/blob/99666e7853a299a6fb3c2ad5974484a3cb8c7739/src/org/mailboxer/saymyname/contact/EclairContact.java#L21).

Good luck
Tom

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have used code given in your mention link but there is no luck, i have formated my code please check does i miss some thing?